# Blank installNotifyURI in OMA Download Descriptors

Tags: mobile, download, descriptor, oma

People can download content (music, images) for their mobile from my server.

I'm trying to use the installNotifyURI-tag of the download descriptors specified by OMA, to be able to find out if the download has been successful.

When the user has downloaded the item I do get a POST to the url I specified in the installNotifyURI-tag.

> <installNotifyURI>http://joynes.se/mytest.php</installNotifyURI>

Although I never get any status code. The POST is just blank. Anyone who knows about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that client (or browser) is sending the POST code/description to the install notify URL specified in the DD file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Openwave's browser emulator v7.0 to test your DD file. This browser supports OMA download v1.0. If you get POST with code/description then issue could be with your test code.